# How can I make a generic Typescript class that accepts an array or an object return a clone of the array or object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a generic class. It has a property `value` with a type of `ValueType` that is set when the class is declared. `ValueType` could be an array or object. I want a method `clone()` to return a clone of the array or object.

```
class MyClass<ValueType> {
  value: ValueType;
  clone(): ValueType {
    if (this.value instanceof Array) {
      return [...this.value]; // TS doesn't like this
    } else {
      return {...this.value};
    }
  }
}
```

For example:

```
const instance = new MyClass<number[]>();
instance.value = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(instance.clone() === instance.value); // false
console.log(JSON.stringify(instance.value) === JSON.stringify(instance.value)); // true
```

But the class definition throws an error on `return [...this.value]`:

> Type ‘any[]’ is not assignable to type ‘ValueType’.
>     ‘any[]’ is assignable to the constraint of type ‘ValueType’, but ‘ValueType’ could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint ‘{}’.

I assume I need to more strongly type `this.value instanceof Array`, since `Array` doesn't specify the array's contents.

How can I fix this?

**Edit:** I fixed it by replacing the line with `return (([...this.value] as unknown) as ValueType);`.

Comment: can you please show us how you defined `ValueType`?

Comment: Sure, just added an example, although the error occurs when the class is first compiled, not when it's instantiated.

Comment: yup, was about to suggest doing what you already did urself :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use TypeScript Generics for a function that can return either objects or arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69736594/how-can-i-use-typescript-generics-for-a-function-that-can-return-either-objects)